# Adding a wire or circuit to a disconnect box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a 40 amp 240v circuit powering a sprinkler pump. There is a disconnect box located near the pump. Can i add a 30 a 120 v circuit to this by replacing disconnect box with a 60 a subpanel or is there a better way ? Need 30 amp 120 v circuit near pump

Comment: What size is the wire and how long is the run?  How many wires are there?  Chances are if it was run with only a 40A pump in mind it's not going to support a 60A subpanel.  Also, are you wanting to run the pump AND a 120v circuit or remove the pump?

Comment: I am not sure wire size. Will have to check. The pump runs overnight so it wont operate at the same time as the 120 v circuit. But both will be on the same run

Comment: Look at the wires, but you're going to need 3 conductors and a ground to run 240v and 120v.  If the wires are in conduit you may be able to pull another wire if needed, but I'd still be worried about the size.  The length of the wire matters too, so measure that as well.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will open it open it up and check

Comment: Is the existing run to the pump disconnect a cable or wires in conduit? If it's the former, then is replacing the run an option?  Also, is this pump attached to a serviced building, or off in the middle of a remote field somewhere?  Furthermore, what is this 30A 120V circuit powering?

Answer (score 2):

Current code would require 4 wires for the sub panel. The 40 amp circuit should have at least #8 wire. With a 40 amp breaker in the main you could feed a 60a sub panel with 4 wires and meet code, if this panel is outside you will need an outdoor panel or a NEMA 3r enclosure. Also the neutral buss needs to be isolated from ground. The ground buss still connects to the case but neutral and ground can only be tied together in the main panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you're fine.  You can use any subpanel that is >= 40A.  60A, 100A, 225A, 400A or whatever.  The breaker in the main panel will protect the wire run,  the subpanel can certainly handle the power.

Our standard advice applies, don't short yourself on panel size.  You might want to add more stuff later.    In fact, you could add a 240V/30A breaker for larger RVs, a 240V/50A breaker for much larger RVs, and a breaker or two for receptacles or lights.   If you're counting, that's 9 spaces so far.